# Unexpected characters at the end of char array - C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I know similar questions have been posted before but I haven't been able to solve the issue for my case.

I have the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    char textChars[4] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
    char noMatchChars[4] = { '1', '2', '3', '4' };
    int tLengths[5] = { 14, 142, 1414, 14142, 141420 };
    int i,j;

    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        char textString1[tLengths[i]+1];
        char textString2[tLengths[i]+1];
        char textString3[tLengths[i]+1];
        char textString4[tLengths[i]+1];
        for (j = 0; j < tLengths[i]; j++)
        {
            textString1[j] = textChars[0];
            textString2[j] = textChars[1];
            textString3[j] = textChars[2];
            textString4[j] = textChars[3];
        }
        textString1[tLengths[i]] = '\0';
        textString2[tLengths[i]] = '\0';
        textString3[tLengths[i]] = '\0';
        textString4[tLengths[i]] = '\0';

        FILE *fp;
        char filepathPattern[14];
        char filepathText[11];
        char iChar[1];
        sprintf(iChar, "%d", i);

        strcpy(filepathText, iChar);
        strcat(filepathText, "_text1.txt");
        fp = fopen(filepathText, "w");
        fprintf(fp, textString1);
        fclose(fp);
        memset(filepathText,0,strlen(filepathText));

        strcpy(filepathText, iChar);
        strcat(filepathText, "_text2.txt");
        fp = fopen(filepathText, "w");
        fprintf(fp, textString2);
        fclose(fp);
        memset(filepathText,0,strlen(filepathText));

        strcpy(filepathText, iChar);
        strcat(filepathText, "_text3.txt");
        fp = fopen(filepathText, "w");
        fprintf(fp, textString3);
        fclose(fp);
        memset(filepathText,0,strlen(filepathText));

        strcpy(filepathText, iChar);
        strcat(filepathText, "_text4.txt");
        fp = fopen(filepathText, "w");
        fprintf(fp, textString4);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

It works as expected for every string expect for textString4 which outputs as 14 'D's as expected followed by a random character and then 14 'C's (the previous string) for some reason but the other strings don't have this issue.

I assumed it was a memory issue but when I replaced 

`char textStringX[tLengths[i]+1];` 

with `char *textStringX = malloc( sizeof(char) * ( tLengths[i] + 1 ) );` 

the result was identical.

I'm new to C so apologies if the solution to this is trivial.

Comment: No matter the value of `i`, when you do `sprintf(iChar, "%d", i);` you ***will*** write out of bounds of the `iChar` array. Don't forget the terminator!

Comment: Also, why don't you just `snprintf` straight into `filePathText`? And copy-pasted code like that looks like, that's a good case for breaking out the common code into a function.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)`  - Is this really what you intend?  `i` will never go beyond the value of 0.

Comment: yeah ryyker it was just while I tested the issue at hand

Comment: I think most of your issues are simply string related.  Make sure you leave enough space to allow for `NULL` termination on all `char` arrays that you intend to use as strings.  A _[C string](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)_ is defined as a NULL terminated char array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issues are string related.  The following lines:

```
char iChar[1];
sprintf(iChar, "%d", i);
```

Are a problem, in that you created a char array, `iChar`, with room for only one `char`, then in the very next line try to use a string function `sprintf` to place two chars into `iChar`: the value of `i` (0 at this point) and the `NULL` char.  You need to create `iChar` with more space:  i.e.

```
char iChar[3]; // will allow printing up to any two digit value + NULL.
```

Eg. zero would look like this:  `|0|\0|\0|`
    99              like this:  `|9|9|\0|`

In C, without a NULL termination, you do not have a *[C string](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)*.  The string functions will not work properly without a C string.

Because the write to `iChar` fails in the call above, the next lines in your code, also string functions always expect NULL terminated char arrays.  anything else will cause them to fail:

```
strcpy(filepathText, iChar);
strcat(filepathText, "_text1.txt");
```

Because I do not know the contents of your text file, I cannot take your code beyond this.   But address these string issues, then step through your code line by line.  I believe most of the issues you cite will be addressed.

Comment: The character is actually called `NUL`, with a single L.

Comment: I didn't know about the null character and string functions before so that's useful to know. I increased iChar's size to 2 and it works now but it saves as filename "_text1.txt" but the whole point of having iChar was to be able to save the file as "0_text1.txt"

Comment: As for the contents of the files they are non-existent until fopen is called

Comment: @Spidey - the name is implementation specific.  On my systems it is defined as NULL:  `#ifndef NULL
#define NULL 0
#endif`.  This define is from my  NI C99 compiler.  What system do you use?

Comment: I got it to work now, Thank you. Just in addition to your answer I will say that I used snprintf(iChar, 2, "%i", i); to prevent out of bounds writing as suggested by @Some programmer dude (220,000 rep WOW!)

Comment: @MelO'Hagan - Glad to help.  Yes, SomeProgrammerDude's suggestions are worth considering.